# Django unable to render form in table format

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a django formset and I am trying to render it row by row. Instead, the form is being render column by column (like a vertical form instead of horizontal). I am using django's form.as_table but it is still not rendering correctly. Any ideads?

form.html:

```
<form id="formset" class="original" action="{% url 'inventory:requests' inventory.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %} 
<!-- <a href="#" id="insert-more"> Add New Row </a> -->
    {{formset.management_form}}
        {% for form in formset.forms %}

            {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            {{ form.errors}}
            <div class='item'>

            <table>{{ form.as_table }}</table>
              <p style=""><a class="delete" href="#">Delete</a></p>

            </div>

        {% endfor %}

        <p><a id="add" href="#">Add another item</a></p>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Request Blocks" id="submitButton">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The form's `as_table` method just uses `<tr></td>` instead of `<div>` to render your form - but it will be rendered visually the same way.

To easily get control over your form, consider using [`django-crispy-forms`](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Here is is how you would make your form render horizontally:

In your `forms.py`, add this (in addition to your normal code):

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit

class ExampleFormSetHelper(FormHelper):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ExampleFormSetHelper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.form_method = 'post'
        self.render_required_fields = True
        self.template = 'bootstrap/table_inline_formset.html'
        self.add_input(Submit("submit", "Save"))
```

Next, in your `views.py`:

```
from .forms import ExampleFormsetHelper, YourFormSet

def formset_view(request):
    formset = YourFormSet()
    helper = ExampleFormSetHelper()
    return render(request, 'template.html',
                 {'formset': formset, 'helper': helper})
```

Finally, in your template, all you need is:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% crispy formset helper %}
```

For more details, the [documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_formsets.html#custom-templates-and-table-inline-formsets) has the specifics.

Comment: I followed your steps and it added a row form(correct layout) above my original form. It did not change the layout of the original form. Do you know how to make it affect my original formset instead of rendering a new form? Also, is there a simpler fix than than using django crispy forms like just editing the html a bit?